# Improve the performance while fetching the data from oracle database

Tags: java, sql, oracle, performance, query-performance

[entity relationship diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tGNx.jpg)

**My database table structures looks like:**

Course Table : (id (primary key), name, descr, and other fields)

Course Activity Relation Table : (course id, activity id ) (composite key - both the columns)

Course Format Relation Table : (course id, format id) (composite key - both the columns)

Course Exam Relation table : (course id, exam id) (composite key - both the columns)

**Currenty I'm fetching it from database following:**

Fetch the course from the db: SELECT query on course based on the condition.

In java code: keep these data in Map, key: courseId, and value: course dto

```
final Map<String, CourseInfo> data = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

Now all the courseIds are stored in key of the map, using that, I will fetch all the **FormatIds**, **ActivityIds** and **ExamIds**

This will be three separate queries to respective tables and than each result will stored in CourseInfo.List formatIds, CourseInfo.List activityIds, CourseInfo.List examIds, the CourseInfos are in map.

```
public static void loadCourseRelatedData(final Connection connection, 
            final Map<String, CourseInfo> data)
            throws SQLException {
        if (!data.isEmpty()) {


            // Load the related data for : ActivityIds
            loadFormatOfferingRelatedDataByTable(connection,  COURSE_ACTIVITY_REL_TABLE_NAME ,
                    COURSE_ACTIVITY_REL_FIELDS.ACTIVITY_ID.name(),
                    COURSE_ACTIVITY_REL_FIELDS.COURSE_ID.name(), data);

        // Load the related data for : formatIds
            loadFormatOfferingRelatedDataByTable(connection,  COURSE_FORMAT_REL_TABLE_NAME ,
                    COURSE_FORMAT_REL_FIELDS.FORMAT_ID.name(),
                    COURSE_FORMAT_REL_FIELDS.COURSE_ID.name(), data);

            // Load the related data for : ExamIds
            loadFormatOfferingRelatedDataByTable(connection,  COURSE_EXAM_REL_TABLE_NAME ,
                    COURSE_EXAM_REL_FIELDS.EXAM_ID.name(),
                    COURSE_EXAM_REL_FIELDS.COURSE_ID.name(), data);

        }
    }
```

The code of loadCourseRelatedData looks like this

```
private static void loadCourseRelatedDataByTable(
            final Connection connection, 
            final String tableName,
            final String listFieldName,
            final String parentField,
            final Map<String, CourseInfo> data)
            throws SQLException {

        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            sql.append(SELECT).append(NEW_LINE);
            sql.append(listFieldName).append(" , ").append(parentField).append(NEW_LINE);
            sql.append(FROM).append(NEW_LINE);
            sql.append(tableName).append(NEW_LINE);
        sql.append(WHERE).append(NEW_LINE);
            sql.append(parentField).append(" in ( ").append(NEW_LINE);
            sql.append(getCommaSeperatedString(data.size(), "?")).append(NEW_LINE);
            sql.append(")");


            try (PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql.toString())) { 

                    // set the perameter
                    int counter = 1;
                    for (String parentId : data.keySet()) {
                        statement.setString(counter++, parentId);
                    }


                try (ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery()) {
                    while (resultSet.next()) {
                        String parentId = resultSet.getString(parentField);
                        String relatedId = resultSet.getString(listFieldName);
                        CourseInfo info = data.get(parentId);


                            switch (tableName) {

                                case COURSE_ACTIVITY_REL_TABLE_NAME:
                                    info.getActivityIds().add(relatedId);
                                    break;

                                case COURSE_FORMAT_REL_TABLE_NAME:
                                    info.getFormatIds().add(relatedId);
                                    break;

                                case COURSE_EXAM_REL_TABLE_NAME:
                                    info.getExamIds().add(relatedId);
                                    break;

                                default:
                                    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                                            tableName + " : Is not valid realtive table");
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
            message.append("\t Related Sql--> ").append(sql).append(NEW_LINE);
            // add the cause Message
            message.append(ex.getMessage());
            throw new SQLException(message.toString(), ex);
        }
    }
```

**Now the question is how can I improve the performance, by avoiding these three extra db calls for related ids ?**

**Approach 1:**

The one approach I took was add a coulmn for each list, i.e. formatIds, activityIds and examIds in Course Table, which will store all the ids with comma seperated values while insert.

So now I will have data in comma separated in CourseTable as well as related table.

Course Table Data will look like,

```
  ID   |   Name   |   FomatIds      |      ActivityIds    |       ExamIds
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  001  | couse.01 | for.1,for.2     |act.1, act.2, act.3  | exm.1, exm.2, exm3 
  002  | couse.02 | for.3,for.4     |act.1, act.3, act.5  | exm.1, exm.2, exm3 
.....
.....
```

Related tables will also available for all the join queries:

**COURSE_ACTIVITY_REL_TABLE_NAME**

```
  COURSEID |   ACTIVITY ID   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  couse.01 | act.1 
  couse.01 | act.2
  couse.01 | act.3 
  couse.02 | act.1
  couse.02 | act.3
  couse.02 | act.5
.....
.....
```

The drawbacks of this approach are

- insertion and updation of Course will be bit more costly
- the main drawback is I can store comma seperated values upto 32000 characters only as VARCHAR2(32000). This is the only one example of Course entity, I have many entities in the application so keeping CLOB instead of VARCHAR2(32000) is not a good idea

Can you please suggest any other approach I can take to improve the perfomance while fetching the data significantly ?

Comment: Why can't you join all the tables together on the courseId, then just do one query ? The best performance gains is making the database doing more of the work rather than you looping over multiple result sets

Comment: Or just have one table instead of three? `(course id, type, type id )`